# use a C++ class with Rcpp to modify it from C or R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm starting to play with rcpp and I'd like to make an object in which I can modify the variables from R or rcpp. 
It seems that making a class is somehow a good solution, as I can modify the fields using the '$' from R, or directly using Rcpp functions. My problem is that when I try to modify a variable of my class from rcpp with a class method, R simply crashes...

below is a small example. The class contains some variables of different types, plus a constructor and two functions, one to print values (to test if changes are trully done when I do something), and one to change the variables of the class.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)

# ODEs can also be described using Rcpp
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '

#include <Rcpp.h>
//#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
class parameters{
public:
  NumericMatrix mat;
  double val;
  int n;
  NumericVector dB;

  parameters(double x):
    val(x) {}

  NumericVector changes(){
    dB[0] = val;
    dB[1] = 12;
    //dB[1] = mean(mat(1,_));
  } 

  void print(){
    Rcout << "val:"  << std::endl << val << std::endl;
    Rcout << "mat:"  << std::endl << mat << std::endl;
  }
};

RCPP_MODULE(ParamModule){
using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<parameters>("parameters")

  .constructor<double>("constructor")

  .method("changes", &parameters::changes)
  .method("print", &parameters::print)

  .field("val", &parameters::val)
  .field("mat", &parameters::mat)
  .field("n", &parameters::n)
  .field("dB", &parameters::dB)
  ;  
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix addVal(NumericMatrix mat, double val, int n){
  int i = 0;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    mat(i, 1) = mat(i,1) + val;
  }

  return mat;
}


')
```

and here is the code that I use to test it:

```
p = new(parameters,5)
str(p) # constructor initialise the field val, ok
p$mat = matrix(5, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
p$print()  # field mat initialised, ok
p$mat = matrix(0.1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
p$print()  # field mat changed, ok
addVal(p$mat, 2, 5)
p$print() # sounds like p is a pointer, ok
p$changes() #...
```

This last line is where the problem occurs (no error message, as R simply crashes).

When I compile the class I have this warning:

```
Warning message:
No function found for Rcpp::export attribute at file215bf0ef501.cpp:8
```

Also, I saw [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf) that I might need to use these two lines:

```
ParamModule = Module("ParamModule")
parameters = ParamModule$parameters
```

but I obtain an error message when I run the last one:

```
Error in Module(module, mustStart = TRUE) : 
  Failed to initialize module pointer: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): no such symbol _rcpp_module_boot_ParamModule in package .GlobalEnv
```

(ParamModule is present as an environment in the global environment).

So, my questions are:

1) Why the function p$changes() is not working

2) Do I need to load paramModule? It doesn't seem to change anything...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small edition of the problematic method resolved the issue. I basically made two (stupid) mistakes:

1) I did not return something, even if when the function was expected to return a numeric vector (I'm surprised that this compiled)

2) I used db[0] instead of db(0)

so the new edited function is:

```
NumericVector changes(){
    dB(0) = val;
    dB(1) = 12;
    //dB[1] = mean(mat(1,_));
    return dB;
  }
```

coatless and Dirk, Thanks for your answers, but it seems that there is no need to use them in a package (as what I did is working correctly). Did I miss something?

Comment: For vectors both `db(0)` and `db[0]` should work.  For multiple indices you must use round parens.

Answer (score 3):

There is support for exposing C++ classes via Rcpp Modules, which you found.

Also in the package, less well-known, but added by John Chambers himself is Rcpp Classes, an extension to Rcpp Modules which seems to be *exactly what you are asking for*.

Have at the example in the [complete example package that ships with Rcpp as a full directory and test](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/tinytest/testRcppClass).  There is also documentation in the package.